# Which one of these Queries are wrong and which is correct (SQL)

Tags: sql, database

[image: Sailor Database]

So some are saying 1 is wrong because B.bid is not accessible after except and we cannot use it after except therefore this will give compiler error

but i don't get it, so we can't use B.bid after except but we can use it after exist? why?

which one is a correct query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes i read that before posting, what is the problem here?

Comment: Please post ***text*** rather than images.  That's why SO has `code` formatting markdown.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to them.) Sample table data and the expected result is always good.

Comment: I mean i apologize i didn't know posting an image instead of text is such a big deal here, also in that link there was no mention of text instead of image.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JohnPence Using text allows people to copy and paste, either for testing or for answer, and allows reformatting where appropriate.  Images just introduce extra work for the Answerer, and so dis-incentivizes them from answering.

Comment: The first. Brackets not balanced

Comment: To all the closers : The use of an image is less than ideal, and the wording isn't great.  That said, however, it ***is*** perfectly clear what is being asked : Which query is syntactically incorrect, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with Query 1.

First, why does it have trailing `))`?  Either they shouldn't be there, or there are some missing `(` elsewhere.

Second, the placement of the `EXCEPT` is wrong.

The example is this...

```
SELECT sname FROM ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)
EXCEPT
SELECT bid   FROM ...
```

But it appears that, for a few reasons, it *wants* to be this...

```
SELECT sname FROM ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT bid FROM ...
                                        EXCEPT
                                        SELECT bid FROM ...
                                       )
```

*(It is currently "excepting" from the main query, not from the sub-query in the WHERE clause.  Moving the `EXCEPT` inside the brackets fixes that.)*

Finaly, even if that was fixed, it still wouldn't help.  The sub-query would then become...

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT bid FROM boats B
            EXCEPT
            SELECT bid FROM reservations R WHERE R.bid = B.bid AND R.sid = S.sid
           )
```

Unfortunately, one query in the `EXCEPT` can't reference the other.

The `R.sid = S.sid` is fine, because that's an inner query referencing and outer query.  *(Those are known as "correlated" sub-queries - in one sense the whole correlated sub-query is executed repeatedly, once for each row in the outer query.)*

But the `R.bid = B.bid` is "jibberish" because the rows in `reservations` are being processed entirely independently from the rows in `boats`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so overall the two queries that are involved in except are independent and cannot reference each other correct? and that is not the case with exist because the inner query can access outer query, did i get this right?

Comment: Indeed, that is correct.